# bash: kill $$ not work?

Tags: linux, bash, kill

The command `kill $$` should kill current bash, but it seems that it doesn't work:

```
$ ps -p $$
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
18179 pts/4    00:00:00 bash
$ kill $$
$ ps -p $$
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
18179 pts/4    00:00:00 bash
```

Why?

Comment: where did you read that `kill $$` should kill current bash?

Comment: maybe this can `kill \`ps -p $$ | awk 'NR==2{print $1}'\``

Comment: besides, why not just `exit`?

Comment: @Antarus: No, that modified one would not kill running bash either.

Comment: oh... have to add -9 like devnull has said 
`kill -9 \`ps -p $$ | awk 'NR==2{print $1}'\``
why the horror? @devnull has the answer :)

Comment: @Antarus `\`ps -p $$ | awk 'NR==2{print $1}'\`` is a highly convoluted way of writing `$$`.

Comment: @Antarus, then, why you don't say `kill -9 $$`.

Comment: @UniMouS read my last comment completely!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure why one would like to `kill` the current shell.  Nevertheless...

`kill PID` would send `SIGTERM` when no signal is specified.  `bash` ignores `SIGTERM` and `SIGQUIT` in the absence of any traps.

You'll achieve the *desired* effect if you were to say

```
kill -9 $$
```

or

```
kill -SIGKILL $$
```

Quoting from the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Signals):

> When Bash is interactive, in the absence of any traps, it ignores
>   `SIGTERM` (so that ‘`kill 0`’ does not kill an interactive shell), and
>   `SIGINT` is caught and handled (so that the wait builtin is
>   interruptible). When Bash receives a `SIGINT`, it breaks out of any
>   executing loops. In all cases, Bash ignores `SIGQUIT`.

Comment: +1. I'm learning a lot from your answers, you're such an expert in those topics. What it is not clear to me is the meaning of `bash ignores SIGTERM and SIGQUIT in the absence of any traps`. Could you explain it a bit further?

Comment: I occassionally `kill -9 $$`, to avoid command-list being appended in history file. I could manually edit history file, but this sometimes becomes shorthand. A dirty way to do it.

Comment: It refers to the `trap` built-in which can *catch* signals.

Comment: @anishsane If you don't want the commands to be appended to the history, you can set the `HISTFILE` variable.  `export HISTFILE=/dev/null`

Comment: @fedorqui To elaborate, you can specify the action to be performed when the shell encounters a given signal.  Say if you want your script to ignore SIGINT and print a friendly message instead, you could say `trap echo "Not permitted!" SIGINT`.

Comment: `HISTFILE` is a good (& importantly, clean) option... Thanks! :-)

Comment: No need to specify the signal if you were in RHEL based version.

Answer (score 0):

When you send a process any signal using kill command, the process can choose to handle the signal as per its wish. (There are a few signals, which cannot be handled.)

When you use `kill $$`, you are actually passing it signal=15 (SIGTERM). It can be handled by a process.

You can google for [linux signal example](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+signal+example) to know HOW it is implemented.

& To answer YOUR question:
 If you pass an un-handlable signal, like SIGKILL(9) or SIGSTOP(19), it will respectively kill/stop a running bash process.